# Call a server Ip simulating domain name

Tags: linux, ip, domain-name

in order to migrate my domain name to my new server, I would like to test it with real domain name.

I think we can call Ip server giving as argument domain name ?

How can I do that ?

Something like that :

IP ADRESS + Domain name as argument ------> Server getting domain name in HTTP_HOST $_SERVER

Thank you !

Edit : I would like it with web browser maybe with addon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the IP address and the host name (separated by a space or tab) in the `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on Linux, `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows). Any application of the system (including your browser) will then use that IP address when you use the specified host name.

Answer (score 3):

Use `telnet`:

```
telnet <ip> 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
HOST: example.com 
<return>
```

It should return a 200 return code and your `/` document for the site `example.com`.

Comment: Thank you, but can't we do that with browser ? (I forgot to specify that)